# Why dosen't it cout s , nr , p and nr1?

Tags: c++, cout

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n,x,y,s=0,p=1;
    int nr,nr1;

    cout<<"n=";
    cin>> n ;
    cout<<"x=";
    cin>> x ;
    cout<<"y=";
    cin>> y;

    while(n!=0)
        {   
            if(n%10%x==0)
                s=s+n%10;
            nr++;
            if(n%10<y)
                p=p*(n%10);
            nr1++;       
        }

    cout<<"s="<<s<<"\n";
    cout<<"nr="<<nr<<"\n";
    cout<<"p="<<p<<"\n";
    cout<<"nr1="<<nr1<<"\n";
}
```

I can type a value for `n , x` and `y` but It doesn't show any result after.
I really don't know what to do. I think that something is wrong with the cout's at the end, but I can't really figure what.
I would really appreciate if someone could help because I need this for an exam in 2 days...

Comment: You never modify `n` in the loop. How would it ever become `0` so the loop ends? You would have found it out very quickly if you just used a debugger to step through the code line by line. A debugger is one of the most important tools in a programmers toolbox.

Comment: Also, I suspect the `if` statements will not do what you expect them to either. This would also have been found out very quickly if using a debugger.

Comment: If you enter `n=0` it will not enter in while loop and if you greater `1` then it won't come out of while loop. Can you explain what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I have to calculate the sum of number n's digits that divide with x and then the product of the digits smaller then y

Comment: @BogdanNacev Check my Recent Answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have a infinite while loop.

You can have your While logic like :

```
while(n!=0) 
{
   n = n%10;

   if(n%x==0)

       s=s+n ;
       nr++ ;

   if(n<y)
      p=p*n ;
      nr1++ ;
}
```

Comment: @BogdanNacev  Can i have the Sample input and output to understand the logic ?

Comment: The ideea is to add the digits of a number n that divide with x and multiply the digits in n that are smaller then y:

Comment: For example I enter 123456 x=2 , so The program has to add 2 4 & 6 because they divide with 2 ! If y is 5 , it should multiply 1*2*3*4 .

Answer (score 0):

This would be the Answer for your Logic. I have used static values, make it dynamic.
Working code with output : http://codepad.org/b5kpWC6y

```
#include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main() {
        int n = 123456;
        int x=2;
        int y=5;

        int s=0;
        int p=1;
        int digit = 0;

        while(n>0)
        {
            digit=n%10;

            if(digit%2==0)
            {
                s=s+digit;
            }
            if(digit<y)
            {
                p=p*digit;
            }

            n=n/10;


        }

        cout<<"\nSum  = " << s;
        cout<<"\nProd = " << p;
    }
```